# Which properties of L-functions can be proven assuming they are objects of a symmetric bimonoidal category?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ct.category-theory, l-functions

The title says it all : assuming all L-functions are objects of a symmetric bimonoidal category  $ (\mathcal{C},\oplus,\otimes,s\mapsto 1,\zeta) $ , where  $ \oplus $  stands for the usual product, what can we prove about L-functions from general theorems about symmetric bimonoidal categories that turns out to have analytic or number theoretic interest ? I know some people here might get angry to see me ask this question but still, it may be insightful.

Comment: Why would you expect this?  What’s the tensor product?  What’s Homs from the Riemann zeta to itself?

Comment: Nothing; with only the given hypotheses $C$ could be a discrete category with only identity morphisms, and then $C$ with this extra structure could be any commutative semiring.

Comment: Under the automorphy and Langlands conjectures, isn't the operator $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} \mapsto\sum_p a_p p^{-s}$ injective on the products and quotients of normalized L-functions and its image is a ring with the pointwise addition and multiplication of functions $\mathcal{P} \to \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Of functions $\mathcal{P} \to \mathbb{C}$ quotiented by "equal on all but finitely many primes" (so that it doesn't contain non-primitive Dirichlet L functions)

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan : I'd be interested in knowing what happens with as many morphisms as possible given this double structure, for different definitions of the tensor product.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN When considering only products and quotients of Dirichlet L-functions what I wrote is trivial, can you show it ?

Comment: @reuns: what exactly do you denote by $\mathcal{P}$? The set of prime numbers?

Comment: of course...${}{}$

Comment: First step : if $f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = \prod_{j=1}^l L(s,\chi_j)^{e_j}, e_j \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $Tf(s)=\sum_p a_p p^{-s} = \sum_p p^{-s} \sum_{j=1}^l e_j\chi_j(p)$. How do you define $Tf(s) + Tg(s)$ and $Tf(s) \times Tg(s)$ to make the image of $T$ a ring ?

Comment: $ Tf(s)+Tg(s)=\sum_{p}p^{-s}(\sum_{j=1}^{l}e_{j}\chi_{j}(p)+\sum_{k=1}^{m}f_{k}\chi_{k}(p)) $  with  $ g(s)=\prod_{k=1}^{m}L(s,\chi_{k})^{f_{k}} $ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69077/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-reuns).

Comment: And $T f(s) \times Tg(s)$ ? And more important how do you know $T f(s) + Tg(s),T f(s) \times Tg(s)$ are in the image of $T$ ?

Comment: T is a projection : the sum of the images is the image of a sum.

Comment: No. We are looking at $\mathcal{D} = \{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = \prod_{j=1}^l L(s,\chi_j)^{e_j}, e_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, no sum here. The question is what is $T \mathcal{D}$ and how to put a ring structure on it. The first step is to write a formula for $\log \prod_{j=1}^l L(s,\chi_j)^{e_j}$ and to define $T$ in term of it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{D} = \{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = \prod_{j=1}^l L(s,\chi_j)^{e_j}, e_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ the set of products and quotients of Dirichlet L-functions and $$T : \mathcal{D} \to \ldots, \qquad T(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}) = \sum_p a_p p^{-s}$$
By multiplicate-ness $\scriptstyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} =\prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1}a_{p^k} p^{-sk})= \prod_p (\prod_{j=1}^l (1-\chi_j(p) p^{-s})^{-e_j})$ $\scriptstyle= \prod_p (\prod_{j=1}^l (1+\chi_j(p) p^{-s}+\mathcal{O}(p^{-2s}))^{e_j}) =\prod_p (\prod_{j=1}^l (1+e_j \chi_j(p) p^{-s}+\mathcal{O}(p^{-2s})))$ $\scriptstyle=\prod_p  (1+\sum_{j=1}^l e_j \chi_j(p) p^{-s}+\mathcal{O}(p^{-2s}))$ thus $a_p = \sum_{j=1}^l e_j \chi_j(p)$ and 
$$T(\prod_{j=1}^l L(s,\chi_j)^{e_j}) = \sum_p p^{-s} \sum_{j=1}^l e_j \chi_j(p)$$

Thus $T\mathcal{D}$ is an abelian group under addition, and exploiting the fact products of Dirichlet characters are Dirichlet characters, there is a natural  ring structure on $T\mathcal{D}$ :

$$(\sum_p p^{-s} \chi_1(p))\times (\sum_p p^{-s} \chi_2(p)) =\sum_p p^{-s} \chi_1(p)\chi_2(p)$$

Then we quotient $T \mathcal{D}$ by the equivalence relation "equal on all but finitely many primes". We then obtain that 
$$T \mathcal{D} = \{ \sum_p p^{-s} \sum_{j=1}^l e_j \chi_j(p), \quad e_j \in \mathbb{Z},\quad \chi_j \text{ primitive Dirichlet charaters}\}$$
Almost by definition, the set of primitive Dirichlet characters is a group $G\cong \lim_{n \to \infty} (\mathbb{Z}/n!\mathbb{Z})^\times$ thus $T \mathcal{D} = \mathbb{Z}[G]$ as a ring (and it is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}[\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times]$ whatever it means in term of L-functions)

The question is if all this works when assuming some Langlands conjectures and replacing the Dirichlet L-functions by the automorphic normalized L-functions $L(s,\pi)$, I'd say yes, since $T (L(s,\pi_1)) \times T(L(s,\pi_2)) = T(L(s,\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2))$.

**What would be the ring structure of $T \mathcal{L}$ ? How would you define $T^{-1}$ ?**

Comment: I'll read your answer tomorrow cause I need to sleep but I doubt "multiplicate-ness" exists in English. I guess you meant "multiplicativity".

Comment: By the way, what is $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN What is your guess.. ?

Comment: The set of supposedly automorphic L-functions ?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Yes. Here what we need is : Euler product, that $F(s) \mapsto T(F(s))$ is injective (ie. functional equation + Ramanujan conjecture + ??), and that the set is closed under $(F,G)  \mapsto F \otimes G(s) \cong \sum_n a_n(F) a_n(G) n^{-s}$ (where $\cong$ means "equal for almost every prime"). About the rest : anything unclear to you ? In particular, do you know the Chinese remainder theorem, the structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z})^\times$ and how to construct all the Dirichlet characters modulo $q$ ? (start with $q=p$, then $q = p_1p_2$)

Comment: I know the general definition of a group and of a ring (though I can't help thinking of the ring of integers instead of a general abstract ring structure) but not what  $ \mathbb{Z}(G) $ can be where  $ G $  is a group. About the Chinese remainder theorem, I only know its concrete formulation in terms of congruences, not in terms of rings.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is the group ring, for example $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}] = \{ \sum_{j=1}^l a_j x^{b_j}, a_j \in \mathbb{C}, b_j \in \mathbb{Z}, l \ge 0\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$. The question is if you can construct all the Dirichlet characters modulo $q$ at least when $q$ is prime. The CRT is the group structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$, thus the ring structure of $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Oops, I meant $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$ (the group law of $\mathbb{Z}$ is in $x^{b_1} x^{b_2} = x^{b_1 + b_2}$). So what about the rest ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69143/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-reuns).

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN
A few examples of Dirichlet characters :  $\chi_3=[0,1,-1]$ means $\chi_3(3n)=0,\chi_3(3n+1)=1, \chi_3(3n+2)= -1$.
$$\chi_1 = [1],\quad\chi_2 = [0,1],\quad \chi_3 = [0,1,-1], \quad \chi_4 = [0,1,0,-1], \quad |\chi_4| = [0,1,0,1], \\ \chi_5 = [0,1,i,-i,-1], \overline{\chi_5} =\chi_5^3= [0,1,-i,i,-1], \chi_5^2 =[0,1,-1,-1,1],  \chi_5^4 = |\chi_5| = [0,1,1,1,1]$$ $\chi_p(np) =0$, $\chi_p(g^a+np) = e^{2i \pi a /(p-1)}$ where  $g$ is a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Comment: Ok for  $\{C}(\Z) $. What is  $ \Z(G) $? Is it the set of finite "sums" of elements of  $ G $ where addition is actually the group law of  $ G $? If so, must  $ G $ be abelian ?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Right now your problem is to understand Dirichlet characters. Yes in the group ring of an abelian group, multiplication is commutative and defined by the group law of $G$ : $( a_1 [g_1])(a_2 [g_2]) = a_1 a_2 [g_1 g_2]$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN So, can you construct all the Dirichlet characters mod $q$ ?

Comment: Yes. The values of such a character are determined by its periodicity and its complete multiplicativity.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Yes ? So what are all the Dirichlet characters mod $q$ ?..

Comment: I need you to specify a concrete value of  $ q $  if you want me to write down the relevant Dirichlet characters  explicitly.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN .... Do you understand my comment above, in particular the definition of $\chi_p$ ? How many Dirichlet characters mod $p$ do you get from $\chi_p$ ? (see how it works for $p = 5$)

Comment: $ p-1 $ since  $ \phi(p)=p-1 $ whenever  $ p $ is prime.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN The question is to construct/define all those $p-1$ Dirichlet characters

Comment: They are of the form  $\chi_{p}^{k} $ where  $ 0\le k\le p-1 $ with  $ \chi_{p}(g) $ a $ p-1$-th root of unity for  $ g $ a generator of  $ \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Because $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic with $p-1$ elements (prove it..) say generated by $g$, then a $\chi \bmod p$ is **entirely** defined by its value $\chi(g)$ (prove it..), and $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ implies $\chi(g)^{p-1} =1$ ie. $\chi(g) = e^{2i \pi c/(p-1)}$ for some $c \in 1\ldots p-1$, which means there are $p-1$ Dirichlet characters $\bmod p$.... What about the Dirichlet characters $\bmod p^k$ and $\bmod pq$ ?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN alors t'en es où..

Comment: What's exactly the definition of a cyclic group ? Otherwise as $ \Z/p\Z^{\times} $ is of order  $ p-1 $ and as a Dirichlet character is a group homomorphism, the order of  $ g $ divides  $ p-1 $  and so does the order of  $ \chi(g) $ .

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN $g$ is a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$, its order is $p-1$. https://www.google.fr/search?q=finite+field+cyclic